# iBeacons and Android compatibility

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I am attempting to create an iBeacon application on Android.

However, I am not having much luck on finding resources on Advertisement formats and parsing for varying values with iBeacon. Apple's API's are exceptionally vague in these areas in describing the format of the packets.

Does anyone have any advice/information on parsing iBeacon ads in Android?

The only resources I can find from the `android-ibeacon` tag are either outdated or resolve in 404 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of those broken links are probably for the Android iBeacon Library 0.x, which was taken down in June of 2014 due to intellectual property issues and replaced with the [Android Beacon Library 2.0](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).

The successor library linked above is free and open source and will detect beacons in a wide variety of formats.

The only trick is that for proprietary beacon formats, you have to add one line of code that sets the `BeaconLayout.`  Just do a Google search for the term "BeaconLayout" and you will get the answer of how to do this.  It's super easy.